# Android, remove adapter from listview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that I'm using for some different adapters, is this right to use following code for removing my `ListView` adapter and clear the `ListView` ?

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Void>(mContext, 0, new Void[]{}));
```

What is your offer? and what is the best way?

**Code has been updated**

Comment: `list.setAdapter(null);list.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: You should consider clearing your `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of setting the adapter to `null`.

Comment: app will crash with `list.setAdapter(null)` in android 2.1

Comment: why you not initialize your adapter with empty list again and call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: cause i have to use that adapter again, and re-filling adapter taking time and make my app slower

Comment: try `setEmptyView` for your listView,

Comment: Why do you want to set empty adapter instead you can hide that listView view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Set Listview.setAdapter(null)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

clear the data in the resource (i.e) what ever your using in the arrayAdapter

```
madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I'm using multiple adapters and by clearing them I had to re-fill them again and it's taking time...

Comment: maintain your arraylist(resource in the arrayAdapter) globally if you want to change the content in the list just the clear the data and add new Data to ArrayList and call madapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it is little bit fast try it

Comment: Is this so bad ??? : `list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Void>(mContext, 0, new Void[]{}));` WHY mate ??

Comment: in some situation, i need to make list empty, and shows a toast that saying "Nothing has found" list must be empty in some cases...

Comment: can you explain what is the exact problem... updating the listView or showing Toast???

Comment: look, there is listview that i'm use for adding criteria for the search, and also im using the list for displaying search result, if search has no result, then list must be empty. and there is some other adapters they cant be clear, cause re-filling them taking time...

Comment: check this link it will helps you :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: Maintaining a global array is a really bad idea...especially if you are recommended Omid use filters. ANy filter operation creates a new List reference.  Which means your external reference no longer points to what the adapter uses.  Can read more about it here: http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/constructor-woes-androids-arrayadapter/